# How can I fit a SARFIMA model in python?

Tags: time-series, arima, arfima

I would like to fit a model of the form $(1 - \phi_1 L - \phi_2 L^2 - \ldots - \phi_p L^p) \times (1 - L)^d \times (1 - L^s) \times y_t = \varepsilon_t
$ in python. $L$ is the lag parameter, $d$ is the differencing order, $p$ is the order of the AR part and $s$ is seasonal period. So actually the model is not too complex, but unfortunately, it seems like no package supports such a model because $0 < d  < 1$ should hold. What can I do to implement this model?

Comment: I would build this in PyMC or Tensorflow Probability, but frankly there are far too many valid options to enumerate. Whatever modelling tool you use, please package and share the model in a professional way (e.g. as a Python package or Kedro product or similar). That makes it easier for others to reproduce your work and also benefit from your efforts.